# How to arrange existing data and sort the sequence according to its priority

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a mobile application that could display and allow the user to sort the items awaiting delivery based on their priority (by moving up and down the items on the screen). And I am displaying the items based on priority (DESC). Every new item inserted is with a default priority of "1". The user could "shift" the priority of an item to any of the sequences in the existing list. I am writing a function in PHP that could check the new arrangement of the edited priority of the item but I can't seem to figure out how would that work in relation to the database

For example, I have 6 items with all default priority of 1. I could arrange it if only the item of any sequence is brought to the top or bottom of the list. How can I do it to resequence the priority in the database if the item is "shift" to the middle of the 2nd or 3rd of the list? How would the priority of all the items being sorted again?

For example with default all default priority is "1",

I could arrange the priority sequence if the last item goes to the top
by making the last item priority to "2",

How am I going to sort if I want the "Item 5" to be in the middle? For example below,

| Item | Priority |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| **5** | **1 (???)** |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |

How could I sort the priority accordingly for all the items again? Even by comparing the DateTime inserted or updated would not be 100% workable as well. The sorting of items are dynamic, the number of items could be infinite and it could be adjusted to any sequence. Appreciate any suggestions! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One solution: add a column `user_order` to your table. Initially the user_order is the same as the item number (on insert of a new item: user_order = item number):

```
 PRIORITY_TABLE
 item    priority   user_order
   1        1          1
   2        1          2
   3        1          3
   4        1          4
   5        1          5
   6        1          6
```

Now the user reshuffles the order and sets priorities. Send that data to the server (I'll use the example you gave)

Then you update the changed priorities: `item 6 => 2`

And you update `user_order` with the order in which the items are send to the server:

```
item 6 => 1
item 1 => 2
item 2 => 3
item 5 => 4
item 3 => 5
item 4 => 6
```

After updates the table look like

```
 PRIORITY_TABLE
 item    priority   user_order
   1        1          2
   2        1          3
   3        1          5
   4        1          6
   5        1          4
   6        1          1
```

Now you can select with two ORDERS: `priority DESC` (high to low) and after that `user_order ASC` (low to high):

```
SELECT * FROM priority_table 
  ORDER BY priority DESC, user_order ASC
```

Comment: How should I do if I want to shift item 6 in between item 2 and 3 in this case?

Comment: Explain. Because in your example you sort on priority first, And that is 2 for item 6, so it will be on top.